# Consider the consecutive value in the data

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I have a data with 3 columns ID, Time and Type; I Need to add a column called "categroy" and the sample data with output is given below:

```
> dput(DF1)
structure(list(ID = c("104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", 
"104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", 
"104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", "104 - 2019-06-03", 
"104 - 2019-06-03", "111 - 2019-05-31", "111 - 2019-05-31"), 
    Time = c("11:17:01", "12:48:51", "13:54:09", "14:14:46", 
    "14:19:46", "14:32:46", "14:19:27", "14:35:12", "15:30:22", 
    "15:31:22", "16:29:12", "09:31:53", "09:31:56"), Type = c("IN", 
    "Out", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "Out", "Out", "IN", "IN", 
    "Out", "IN", "Out"), Category = c("Include", "Include", "Include", 
    "Exclude", "Exclude", "Exclude", "Exclude", "Include", "Include", 
    "Exclude", "Include", "Include", "Include")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Being a swipe data sorted based on time and ID, need to consider if the person is marked as "IN" and then "Out" makes it a one proper entry. I mark both the IN and OUT as "Include" if it happens sequentially. Sometime, there are multiple consecutive IN and OUT entry and in those cases I mark the First "IN" as include and the "last "OUT" as include. The in between entries are marked as exclude. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe be you could explain the rule that you use to classify an entry as Include or Exclude, and show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Saudic told you in his comment, the main challenge of your question was to actually understand your classification. Since I like puzzles, here is my attempt.

As I understood it, you want an alternating of In and Out, for each ID, sorted by Time.

Here is the code to get the inclusion criteria:

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)

x = read.table(text = "
ID  Type  Time
104-2019-06-03  In  11:17:01
104-2019-06-03  Out 12:48:51
104-2019-06-03  In  13:54:09
104-2019-06-03  In  14:14:46
104-2019-06-03  Out 14:19:27
104-2019-06-03  In  14:31:12
104-2019-06-03  Out 15:21:51
104-2019-06-03  In  15:30:22
104-2019-06-03  Out 16:29:12
104-2019-06-04  In  14:31:12
104-2019-06-04  Out 15:21:51
104-2019-06-04  Out 15:30:22
104-2019-06-04  Out 16:29:12
", header=T) %>% 
  mutate(Time = chron(time=Time))

# x[c(4,11,12),"Category"] = "Exclude"
# x$Category = x$Category %>% replace_na("Include")

x %>% 
  arrange(ID, Time) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    Category = ifelse(Type=="In", Type!=lag(Type), Type!=lead(Type)),
    Category = ifelse(is.na(Category)|Category==TRUE, "Include", "Exclude")
  )
```

The key here is to use `lag` and `lead` to test if the next/previous row has the same value. Since you want the last or the first, this depends on the value of `Type`. Then you can clean the column by translating to "Include" or "Exclude".